# Separate directories from a column using python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am new to Pyhthon, and have been stuck with some work.
I have a .csv file, with 7 columns.
The first column contains path to certain files, eg:

```
Name
a/b/c.xyz
m/n/o/p.sad
p/q/r/s/t/u.asas
```

I need to separate the directories(path) to the files, and owners being `'a'`, `'m'`, `'p'` for their respective rows. I have imported the .csv file using pandas. I have read that os.path could be of some help. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.Also, the data I'm working on is pretty big, so need to take care about the overhead in executing the script.

Thanks.

Comment: do you want to split owners and paths into two columns?

Comment: Yes sir, that is what I intend to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to find the owner and file name, it could be done by split.

```
import csv

owner,file =[],[]
with open(filePath,'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in reader:
        owner.append(line.split('/')[0])
        file.append(line.split('/')[-1])
```

if you need to find the file path and remove the owner, it can be achieved by split and os.path.join

```
import csv
import os
owner,file =[],[]
with open(filePath,'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in reader:
        owner.append(line.split('/')[0])
        file.append(os.path.join( *line.split('/')[1:] ))
```

os.path.join example:

```
 string = 'p/q/r/s/t/u.asas'
    os.path.join( *string.split('/')[1:] )
    output:
    'q\\r\\s\\t\\u.asas'
```

Answer (score 1):

the `os` module you mentioned knows three different split variants

`os.path.split   os.path.splitdrive  os.path.splitext`

If you just want the first part of your string just use `<str>.split('/')[0]`

```
>>> 'p/q/r/s/t/u.asas'.split('/')
>>> 'p'
```

I'd also recommend to use the build-in `csv` module to read your file. pandas seems like overkill.

Here a good [source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) on how to use the module. I especially like the `csv.DictReader` class.

Comment: `os.path.dirname` and `os.path.basename` could also be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

is that what you want?

```
In [64]: df
Out[64]:
               Name
0         a/b/c.xyz
1       m/n/o/p.sad
2  p/q/r/s/t/u.asas

In [66]: df.Name.str.extract(r'(?P<owner>.)(?P<path>/.*)', expand=True)
Out[66]:
  owner             path
0     a         /b/c.xyz
1     m       /n/o/p.sad
2     p  /q/r/s/t/u.asas
```